# How to add humburger icon in MasterDetailPage in xamarin.Forms(iOS)

Tags: xamarin.ios, navigation, xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer

I am new to Xamarin.Forms. I am creating NavigationPage for both iOS and Android. All the thing set well.see the Below ScreenShot.

in Android this is look way

[image]

but in iOS it is not display well

[image]

**Code :**

**MasterPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="DroidDrawer.MasterPage" Padding="0,0,0,0" Title="Menu" Icon="humburger">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0,20,0,0" BackgroundColor="#004F80">
            <ListView x:Name="listView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="#0072BA">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0" Margin="12,10,0,10" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="24" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,13,0,10" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**MasterPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DroidDrawer
{
    public partial class MasterPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ListView ListView { get { return listView; } }
        public MasterPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var masterPageItem = new List<MasterPageItem>();
            masterPageItem.Add(new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "Home",
                IconSource = "nav_home.png",
                TargetType = typeof(HomePage)
            });
            masterPageItem.Add(new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "CSS",
                IconSource = "nav_appointment.png",
                TargetType = typeof(CssPage)
            });
            masterPageItem.Add(new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "Javascript",
                IconSource = "nav_feedback.png",
                TargetType = typeof(JavascriptPage)
            });
            masterPageItem.Add(new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "Html",
                IconSource = "nav_financialinfo.png",
                TargetType = typeof(HtmlPage)
            });

            listView.ItemsSource = masterPageItem;

        }
    }
}
```

Any Help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After 6 hour I got the solution for my problem was the Icon size is too large to it is display so big in the Screen. After setting 30*30 Image size it is solve the problem...